# Two-way SSL authentication with Apache - CA certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm reading tutorial http://www.impetus.us/~rjmooney/projects/misc/clientcertauth.html 
There is a part "Install the CA Certificate on the Web Server":

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
... 
SSLCACertificateFile /var/www/conf/ssl.crt/ca.crt
...
</VirtualHost>
```

I wonder why I have to add on www server CA certificate and not generated client or server signed by CA certificate. CA certificate looks like it is universal and widely available for everyone, so somebody could sign in CA own csr and try to login ony my server.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

A client certificate is used to identify a specific client. Usually you have multiple clients and each of them got their own certificate from your CA. While you could give the server all client certificates you ever generated (I don't know if this is possible with apache), it is much easier to give the server just the CA which issued these certificates and let the server verify, that the client certificate was issued by this CA.

Comment: Hi Steffen thank you for reply. If I have own CA I can sing or not certificate and it could have sense. But how about commercial CA? When I send client csr to Commercial CA it doesn't use same key and crt for all clients certificates?

Comment: Csr and key should be generated by the client and the key should be known only to the client, same as you would do with server certificates. Otherwise you would not be able to identify a specific client by its certificate. Thus csr and key will be different for each client, but the CA will usually be the same.

Comment: Hi @SteffenUllrich do you know if exists any form to validate only one certificate (witch her public key) by Apache? No by CA, I need validate by her public key (*.cer file).
thanks

Comment: @mreig: please don't ask new questions in comments.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich sorry, done at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74121698/apache-validate-only-certificate
thanks,